# Applying styler to table replaces the values with style as plain text

Tags: python, pandas, highlight, pandas-styles

I have a very huge dictionary which I am trying to highlight few rows with matching keys. To highlight specific rows in the HTML table generated from a dictionary, I am using below code. After running this code, my matching row is being displayed as `Name: background-color: yellow`, `Age: background-color: yellow` `City:background-color: yellow` Is there a way I could apply it as style. Any help is much appreciated

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    "1": {"Name": "John", "Age": 25, "City": "New York"},
    "2": {"Name": "Jane", "Age": 30, "City": "London"},
    "3": {"Name": "Mike", "Age": 35, "City": "Paris"}
}
highlighted_rows = ["1", "3"]  # Specify the rows to highlight
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient="index")
df.insert(0, "Count", range(1, len(df) + 1))

# Add a CSS class to the specified rows for highlighting
df.loc[df.index.isin(highlighted_rows), :] = "background-color: yellow"

html_table = df.to_html(index=False, escape=False)
# Save the HTML table to a file
with open("table.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(html_table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your indexing strategy, you should use [`styler.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html):

```
def color(df):
    mask = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
    mask.loc[df.index.isin(highlighted_rows), :] = "background-color: yellow"
    return mask
    
html_table = (df.style.apply(color, axis=None)
                .hide(axis='index').to_html(escape=False)
              )
```

Output:

[image]